# when received mqtt message, how to wake up android early

Tags: android, push-notification, mqtt, wakeup

I use MQTT libary on Android.

I am curious about when received mqtt message, how to wake up device fastest without GCM Service.

When device gets into deep sleep then received mqtt message, 
To handle this message almost 5~6sec. (wakeup time must be 1~3sec)
I already added code of WakeLock in MessageArrived method.

Can I get your feedback?

Comment: Is there a reason for not using GCM? In my experience MQTT is not very reliable if the device is asleep. When I implemented a MQTT chat I ended up sending GCM pushs to wake up the device.

Comment: Thank you for answer! unfortunately, GCM using is not permit. Do you have any otehr idea?

Comment: Hi, any updates on this question? Did you sort this out?